# Node: Find mailto: section with cheerio

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

https://www.apotek1.no/vaare-apotek/ostfold/raade-474

On the center of the website above you can see an email address wrapped into "mailto" html section. With jQuery it is fairly easy to fetch this mail as a string like this:

```
$('a[href^="mailto:"]').text
```

However when I want to use node.js with cheerio library (which should work like jquery) It simply doesn't work.

```
 let      $  = cheerio.load(html) // launching cheerio with html code requested from website
 let mailto  = $('a[href^="mailto:"]').text // this will give me empty string
 let mailto1 = $('a[href^="mailto:"]').text() // this will return whole body of the function
```

How can I fetch address from mailto section using cheerio?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a[href^="mailto:"]').attr("href")
```

Try with this one this will return you the href property value and after you  can replace mailto: like

```
$('a[href^="mailto:"]').attr("href").replace(‘mailto:’, ‘’)
```

Hope this can help you.